# USA Global Entry member travelling with ESTA-only companion

Tags: esta, global-entry, trusted-traveler

Can a Global Entry-registered person choose to use the standard immigration lines?

Context:

My wife and I travel to the USA occasionally, sometimes together, sometimes separately. Currently we both have ESTA registrations.

My understanding is that in order to join the Global Entry system we will each need to be interviewed while in the USA. It is quite likely that we may join Global Entry on different occasions and hence the possibility arises that we may enter the USA together when we both have ESTA but only one of us has completed the Global Entry process.

While we could separate at immigration each going to our own lines this just adds complexity; much prefer to keep together. That implies we'll both need to follow the slow immigration line. I can't see why this should be an issue, but I can find any guidance on the topic.

Comment: Have you checked whether you are eligible for Global Entry issued in the USA, rather than through your home country?

Comment: My understanding is that you can do all the processing in the home country but that the final interview must be in the USA.

Comment: Apparently once you've visited the US, on subsequent visits where you are using the VWP you can use the automated passport kiosks. This may make Global Entry slightly less attractive.

Comment: Yes, I believe that APC is possible, and I see that it's available at EWR. However, having travelled through there twice recently I've not see any direction for non-US citizens to use those kiosks.

Comment: If I were you, I would be inclined to suspect that the signs were wrong and just walk up to the kiosk.  In general, I've found, direction about which line to join is oversimplified.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the 9th question at https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/frequently-asked-questions:

> **As a Global Entry member, am I required to use the Global Entry kiosk when entering the United States?**
>
> No. Global Entry members can choose not to use the kiosk and can be processed by CBP officers.